# evaluate this integral using gauss's divergence theorem

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, gaussian-integral

$$\iint\bar N \cdot\bar F ds$$
where $\bar F=4xi+3yj-2zk$ and $S$ is the surface bounded by $x=0, y=0,z=0$ and $2x+2y+z=4$.
I solved this question 
$\nabla\cdot\bar F=4+3-2=5$but the $$\iiint\nabla\cdot\bar Fdv=\iiint5dxdydz$$
but what will be limits of that triple integration?

Comment: the $ div=5$ which is a constant so the integral is $ 5.volumeincludedbyclosedsurface$

Answer (score 1):

The volume is bounded by the given four planes
$$
x = 0 \\
y = 0 \\
z = 0 \\
2x + 2y + z = 4
$$
thus a tetraeder with vertices $(0,0,0), (2,0,0), (0,2,0), (0,0,4)$.

[image: scene]

You have to decide some parametrization for it.

E.g. $z$ varying from $0$ to $4$, $y$ from $0$ to $(4-z)/2$, $x$ from $0$ to $(4-2y-z)/2$.

Answer (score 1):

There are two facts all vector calculus students should know.  1.  The volume of a (generalized) cylinder is area of the base times the perpendicular height.  2.  The volume of a (generalized) cone is $1/3$ area of the base times the perpendicular height.

The volume in your question is a generalized cone.  The base is a triangle of area $2$.  The height is $4$.  So the volume is $8/3.$

The value of your triple integral is, then, $5 \times 8/3 = 40/3.$